# How to create a table in ADX with field with dot

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to create a table with `dot.sample` as a field and getting `"query could not be parsed"` error.

Tried to escape it using backslash and its not working.

How I create table:

```
.create table testingTwo (dot.sample: string, normalfield: string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#identifier-naming-rules

for example:

```
.create table MyTable (['dot.sample']: string, other_column: int)
```